# Script to create a follow up action on an email message in Outlook

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook, ms-office

I get two messages everday.  The second message must arrive within 3.5 hours; if not, I have to start figuring out what went wrong with the second process that kept that email from getting sent.

Here's what I'd like to see happen.

1. Message one arrives
2. A rule executes and flags the message for follow-up (or anything really) 3.5 hours from that time.

There's a "run script" option in Outlook's Rules Wizard that I would use to trigger the script.

**Bonus Points:**

3 . When the second email arrives, it clears the follow-up flag from the first message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did:

```
Sub MyRule(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
   MsgBox "Mail one has arrived: " & Item.Subject
   Dim newMail As Outlook.MailItem
   Set newMail = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
   newMail.To = Item.To
   newMail.Subject = "!!!Start looking for issues!!!!"
   newMail.Body = "Something might have gone wrong with the process.. You did not receive any closing mail for " + Item.Subject + " received on " + Item.ReceivedTime
   newMail.DeferredDeliveryTime = DateAdd("h", 3.5, Now)
   newMail.Send
End Sub
```

This mail sits in your outbox for 3.5 hours and then gets sent.

This works only if you keep outlook running about 3.5 hours after the first mail. Till then when you try to close outlook, it will say that there are items in the outbox which are not sent. You can safely ignore this warning, but make sure that you have Outlook running afterwards.

(some of the code was written and tested in Outlook. but the body and subject part i have typed outside the VB Editor. You might have to resolve minor errors.)

**EDIT**:: for Bonus points..

```
Sub MyRuleForMessageTwo(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim myitem As Outlook.MailItem
    Set OutboxItems = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderOutbox).Items
    Set myitem = OutboxItems.GetFirst
    Do While Not (myitem Is Nothing)
        If myitem.Subject = "!!!Start looking for issues!!!!" Then
            myitem.Delete
            Exit Do
        End If
        Set myitem = OutboxItems.GetNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

You can play around with the matching criteria if you expect more than one message to be sitting in your outbox and you want to delete only one.

Comment: I have NO idea why I did not accept this answer years ago!  So sorry!  Great outside the box thinking!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it sounds like you are creating a bizarre Rube Goldberg contraption, but that's going to be your problem, not mine, so have fun!

[image]

The way I would do this is to write a simple script that iterates through all messages in the inbox. Set the script to run every five minutes or so.

When it finds the first message of a pair, it records the time that message arrived. If it finds the second message, it checks to make sure that it arrived within 3.5 hours. If it doesn't find the second message, it checks if 3.5 hours have elapsed and warns you if they have.

There is no need to set flags on the first message. This doesn't get you any additional information that your script can't figure out later.

Comment: Well, what troubles me about your answer is not that JS is answering one of my posts for the first time (well, the actual first time was when your account got hacked and 'you' edited one of my questions but that wasn't really you), but that you have a diagram of my toothpaste dispenser (patent pending btw). PS: I saw your FogBugz and Kiln pitch in Minneapolis a few months ago and enjoyed it very much 80) PPS: my bird Mort looks nothing like that. PPS: the new beta version also turns on the water; very time saving.